# Is it correct to say "We've been stood, standing..."

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context

What exactly one mean when they say "stood standing" in a sentence?

*Brace yourself...*

[Example:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWjM2SE7LaY&feature=youtu.be&t=2m07s)

> "Mr. rumbold, I have a complaint, and I am unanimous in this! We've been **stood, standing**, waiting downstairs for that lift, and it wasn't working..."

[One more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su2fyvmxAzI&feature=youtu.be&t=4m31s):

> "Oh, I'm worn out to start with. I have **stood standing** in the bus all the way

[And a similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYIG_jverjw&feature=youtu.be&t=4m40s):

> "We have been **sat**, **sitting** here for half an hour and nothing arrived, except you"

Is this phrase grammatically correct, or might it just be a script error? Can you please explain when this type of emphasis can be used, and if it's commonly being used?

Comment: I suspect that it's an error by the actor or character; they started to say "We've been stood" and then corrected themselves.  "stood standing" isn't something you would normally say in English.

Comment: @stangdon I see. I asked this because it happens [more than once](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su2fyvmxAzI&feature=youtu.be&t=4m31s) (Yes, it's sad, but i'm a big fan of AYBS)

Comment: That's all wrong, not with equal words, no. You can, however say: We have been standing, looking at the ocean.

Comment: I liked it when Mrs. Slocombe said, "We've been stood standing." I interpreted it to mean "left" or forgotten about, ignored, as in the similar expression "stood up". It's actually a great expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These repeated usages from the television series "Are you being served?" are probably a literary device to suggest that the speaker lacks education.

That said, this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stood%20standing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstood%20standing%3B%2Cc0) shows that usage in written English is rare but  has risen consistently since the 1850's apart from during the two world wars, and is more common in American English than British English.

Typically, **stood** functions as a verb in the sentence and **standing** is used to attach an adjective that describes the way in which the person is standing. Here is a typical example:

> He stood standing still next to the oak tree, next to which Dronian was buried. [Dreamweaver](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=pxdfjJzlkc8C&pg=PT251&dq=%22stood%20standing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh_Ifz6qvTAhWKalAKHXYhDcg4ChDoAQhNMAg#v=onepage&q=%22stood%20standing%22&f=false) - Nicole Weisensee (2011)

Most instances are run of the mill fiction, but there is one notable exception- one John Keats, maybe exercising a bit of poetic licence:

> Until he reach’d the great main cupola;
>   There **stood standing** fierce beneath, he stampt his foot,
>   And from the basements deep to the high towers
>   Jarr’d his own golden region  Hyperion book 1 -  John Keats (1820)

Note that **stood** has been edited out from some editions.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for having this research for me and solving the mystery once and for all